# Windows Identity Foundation in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, claims-based-identity

I've been reading about SharePoint 2010's Claims based authentication support.  At this point, my shop has several clients who may not upgrade for a while, however.  In making our other services claims compatible, we're wondering if claims based authentication is realistic without a great deal of reworking of existing code in our 2007 installations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I planned on implementing Geneva (now WIF) in MOSS 2007 last year for a blog series, but I didn't get around to it.

When I looked into it, it was entirely possible, and just required extending your SharePoint site in the same manner you would for a Forms Based Authentication provider.

If you need more info, I can go back to my notes and see if I can scrounge up some detail.

## Edit

Check out [this blog post](http://quickanddirtyscripting.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/claims-based-authentication-with-sharepoint-2007/) for more information on setting up claims on SharePoint 2007.

Comment: If you were able to find something without too much trouble, I'd sure appreciate it.

Comment: I think I've seen a tutorial about this on the WIF team blog.